# Combinatorics: choose 10 mathematicians out of $18$ mathematicians and $6$ physicists out of $12$ physicists.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many possible outcomes can be found in these situations?

(a) A board of $10$ mathematicians and $6$ physicists is to be selected from a group of $18$ mathematicians and $12$ physicists.

So for (a), I believe I should use variations without repetitions method.

This leads to $\dfrac{18!}{10!8!} = 43,758$     and     $\dfrac{12!}{6!6!}= 924$
Total possible outcomes $= 44,679$

and then I just add them both in the end, but my friend says that I'm wrong and that I need to multiply the values instead. Is that correct? But why if it is so?

Comment: Multiplying is correct; selecting the mathematicians and selecting the physicists are independent of each other.

Comment: Multiply is correct.  To gain insight, try it with a smaller set.  One where you can comfortably list all the cases.

Comment: So then every time there is more than 1 value I'll have to multiply them because they are independent of one another? In what situation would they not be independent?

Comment: You add when two events are mutually exclusive, meaning that they cannot occur at the same time.  Consider the question: How many outfits can a woman form if she has $10$ blouses, $5$ pairs of trousers, $4$ skirts, and $3$ dresses?  Since the woman either wears a blouse and a pair of trouser, a blouse and a skirt, or a dress, the number of outfits she can form is $10 \cdot 5 + 10 \cdot 4 + 3 = 50 + 40 + 3 = 93$.  Here, we assume the choice of blouse and trousers is independent (which may not be the case if they clash), so we multiply.  We make the same assumption for a blouse and skirt combo.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation @N.F.Taussig